# Automatically connecting to a VPN at startup and sending email with IP address

Tags: windows-7, vpn

On Windows 7 SP1 Home, how to:
1) setup an automatic VPN connection at startup (in the background) - every time after a particular user logged onto computer there should be 3-5 attempts to connect to a particular VPN (user info/password already saved for this connection)
2) after successfully establishing the VPN connection, send an email in background with VPN's "clients IPv4 address" in the message body

Comment: 1) Use a scheduled task when the user logs in to dial a predefined VPN profile using `rasdial`. 2) use the script to ping a remote IP on the VPN destination and when you get a valid reply send your email

Comment: An app (e.g. .net app) running in the background, starting automatically after user logon, and pinging an IP in VPN subnet. Seems legit. Thx @BigChris!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to connect to a VPN at startup?](https://superuser.com/questions/737799/how-to-connect-to-a-vpn-at-startup)